# Zinc HTTP Components and VisualWorks

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

is there a way to use the Zinc HTTP Components in VisualWorks and has anybody done this successfully?

Henrik

Answer (score 2):

VisualWorks has its own HTTP framework (packages HTTP, HTTPS etc). Load NetClients from Parcel Manager under Networking. Its API is similar but not equal to Zinc.

You can look into the CloudFork (API for Cloud services like OpenID, OAuth AWS, etc.) for an example of portability layer to use the HTTP clients from Squeak, Pharo, VA and VisualWorks the portable way.

Comment: Thanks Janko. This seems to mostly cover the client-side of HTTP though. I would also need the server-side. Visualworks' own server seem to be overkill and not suitable compared to Zinc - but maybe that's not the case...